# Model tracking with Flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

How can I effectively implement model tracking in ARCore or ARKit using Flutter to create a detailed 3D model of a room?  and how can I optimize the accuracy of the model detection and tracking system?